# Cannot run Doxygen from Meson on a C++ project

Tags: c++, configuration, doxygen, meson-build

I cannot run Doxygen through Meson's configuration.

This is the related code in `meson.build`:

```
doxygen = find_program('doxygen')
...
run_target('docs', command : 'doxygen ' + meson.source_root() + '/Doxyfile')
```

The doxygen executable is successfully found:

> Program doxygen found: YES (/usr/bin/doxygen)

However, when launched, I get this error message:

> [0/1] Running external command docs.
>   Could not execute command "doxygen /home/project/Doxyfile". File not found.
>   FAILED: meson-docs

Running it manually from the command line it works:

```
/usr/bin/doxygen /home/project/Doxyfile
doxygen /home/project/Doxyfile
```

What is wrong in my `meson.build` configuration?

Comment: I don't know about meson. But what happens when you use in the meson build: `run_target('docs', command : 'where doxygen ')`

Comment: @albert - I get: `Could not execute command "where doxygen ". File not found.`
`FAILED: meson-docs`

Comment: @albert - However, if I run `where doxygen` through bash, I get: `where: command not found`

Comment: Sorry, the command should have been `which` not `where` (mixed up 2 operating systems)

Comment: Same result: `Could not execute command "which doxygen ". File not found.` . But now it works from the command line.

Comment: It is the latest version: 0.47.2

Comment: With: `run_target('docs', command : 'ls')` it works correctly, and prints the directory contents.

Comment: `ls` is a build in command. What is the outcome of the `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: `echo $PATH` does not work: `Could not execute command "echo $PATH". File not found.` Same with a simple `echo`, so the error does not depend on $PATH.

Comment: Sorry beats me, nearly looks like the spaces are filtered out (try as command `ls -ls`.

Comment: `Could not execute command "ls -ls ". File not found.`

Comment: Something for a meson expert...

Comment: @albert - Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to reference [manual](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html),

> **command** is a **list** containing the command to run and the arguments to
>   pass to it. Each list item may be a string or a target

So, in your case the whole string is treated by meson as command, i.e. tool name, not as command + arguments. So, try this:

```
run_target('docs', command : ['doxygen', meson.source_root() + '/Doxyfile'])
```

Or it could be better to use directly the result of **find_program()**:

```
doxygen = find_program('doxygen', required : false)
if doxygen.found()
  message('Doxygen found')
  run_target('docs', command : [doxygen, meson.source_root() + '/Doxyfile'])    
else
  warning('Documentation disabled without doxygen')
endif
```

Note that if you want to improve docs generation with support of Doxyfile.in, take a look at [custom_target()](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#custom_target) instead and example like [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/blob/a52f0db3c54b093a2c44dce37ea6dd5582a19c5a/doc/api/meson.build).

Comment: The highlighting of the word **list** does shine a good light on it as well as the example you give.